# What is the argument between Rashi and the Ra'avid about the meaning of HaMelech HaKadosh

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, words, rashi, mysticism-kabbalah

I was reading בחינת דת, a work of Hashkafa by [Elias ben Moise del Medigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elia_del_Medigo) and in it [he references](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9403&st=&pgnum=48&hilite=)* an argument between Rashi and the Ra'avid regarding the meaning of HaMelech HaKadosh. The context is apparently that some use this as evidence that one (or both?) of them had access to Kabbalah, and he is dismissive of the claim - however he neither describes the nature of the claim nor refutes it.

What is the argument and where is each found in the original works of Rashi and the Ra'avid respectively?

Brownie points: How does that argument relate to Kabbalah?

<sup>*I have seen a claim that the commentary on the bottom of this print was written by a Maskil.</sup>

Comment: Which Ra'avad?.

Comment: @yez, he doesn't specify.

Comment: The only machloqes I can think of doesn't seem to be related: Rashi (among the majority) says that someone who ends the 3rd berakhah "haKel haQadosh" during 10 Yemei Teshuvah must repeat the berakhah. The Raavad says one does not.  This machloqes is in the Tur (OC 582 http://j.mp/1Z8uhO2 )

Comment: @Yishai, do you have a link for the sefer online? It would be nice to see the text you are referring to.

Comment: @Yishai, here's the link. You should edit it at the appropriate page into your question. Which page?  http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9403&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=

Comment: @YaacovDean, See my updated question. That's what happens when I go from memory, although I don't think it substantially changes anything.

Comment: @Yishai, it always helps to look at the actual text. Now you have an answer. Shabbat shalom!

Comment: The commentary on the bottom was written by Rav Yashar Reggio. He was a "modern" Italian Rav from the late 1700 and early 1800. He was independently minded. Call him what you want. I am tempted to +1 just for the Bechinas HaDas reference.

Comment: Eliyahu Delmedigo was an 'Avveroist' according to his bio. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elia_del_Medigo  That means he was a follower of Avveroes, the Islamic scholar who specialized in the study of the Greek philosophy of Aristotle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averroes    See also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averroism  In general, the study of 'philosophy' other than that found in Torah is prohibited.  https://www.dailyhalacha.com/Print.asp?ClipID=531

Comment: Eliyahu Delmedigo's descendent, Yosef Shlomo Delmedigo followed a similar path. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Solomon_Delmedigo  It was for this reason that some Jewish communities rejected some of the writings of the latter. This is discussed in Shem HaGadolim from the Chida and other places.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, he was a professor of philosophy in Italy, thus had secular students.

Comment: @Yishai, I understand. Just remember the story of Hanukkah. ;-)

Comment: @mevaqesh, if [this statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Samuel_Reggio) in Wikipedia is accurate: "Reggio's main point is that most of the Talmudic ordinances were not intended for perpetual observance; they were practiced only by the rigorous Pharisees. It was not until much later, he declares, that the casuists ("poseḳim") established such ordinances as a part of the Law." Then I would say it is an appropriate characterization.

Comment: @Yishai it is a meaningless characterization unless one first defines his or her terms...Many rabbis have had positions that were original and or lone views. Which of these render them "maskilim" and which of them do not. I am not saying there are no answers; just that one needs to define one's terms for them to be meaningful. It is also useful to appreciate the cultural milieu. Many characters were simultaneously respected by both rabbinic and enlightened circles; e.g. Shlomo Yehudah Rappaport.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the text correctly, Del Mediggo is referring to the idea that the Ra'avad is giving in his explanation of the phrases,  'HaMelech HaKadosh' and 'Al tashiveinu', that they are referring to the Holy name of 72 triplets (216 letters). This name relates to converting 'Gevurot' to 'Chassadim' which is why this would be related to the 10 days of teshuvah, meaning from Rosh HaShanah to Yom Kippur. The gematria of 'Gevurah' (גבורה) is 216. While the gematria of 'Chesed' (חסד) is 72. This name was also associated with changing Moshe's staff into the serpent and back again.

And Rashi says in his commentary, that this name is not necessarily associated with this name and to study of 'Kabbalah' and is not restricted to those who study Kabbalah alone. Rashi comments on this phrase, 'HaMelech HaKadosh', in Gemara Brachot 12b.

I don't happen to have the Ra'avad on Brachot handy, but that is where I would look for the 'Kabbalistic' explanation. It is possible that he may discuss the subject in his comments to Hilchot Tefilla from the Rambam in Mishnah Torah. Ra'avad was from Provence and was a recognized authority in Pnimiyut HaTorah in his day.

Comment: Without looking at the sources, I can be pretty sure that Rashi dos no says in his commentary, that this name is not necessarily associated with this name and to study of 'Kabbalah' and is not restricted to those who study Kabbalah alone. Whatever sorts of mysticism existed in Rashi's time were not known as kabbalah. This term seems to postdate him by centuries.

Comment: "Ra'avad was from Provence and was a recognized authority in Pnimiyut HaTorah in his day." Source? In reality Raavad never once mentions a single "kabbalistic" idea in all of his writings.

Comment: BTW: did the term "penimiyut HaTorah" even exist before the Acharonim?

Comment: @mevaqesh, you are correct. That assessment, that choice of words, is by the author of "Bechinat HaDa'at". He is looking at Rashi on Brachot discussing the phrase, 'HaMelech HaKadosh' and saying it is not the way the Ra'avad explains the same words. Delmedigo says the meaning of those words is not restricted to those who study Kabbalah.

Comment: @mevaqesh, From what I have learned over the years, your understanding of the mystical parts of Torah learned in Rashi's time is not correct. The nomenclature was different. Part of that had to do with the permission to disseminate being very restricted then. A good explanation of that subject can be found in the introduction to Sefer Shomer Emunim HaKadmon. I will, bli neder, be providing you with background on this in another post where we have discussed this recently.